# Reset textboxes with jquery does not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have the following program with a submit form and a javascript part, which should reset my textboxes, but after submitting nothing happens.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Label("Name")</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("name", null, new { id = "tb1" })</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>@Html.Label("Mail")</td>
                    <td>@Html.TextBox("mail", null, new { id = "tb2" })</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
                
            <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="clear" />
        }
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            
        });

        function clear() {
                $("#tb1").val("");
                $("#tb2").val("");
        }

    </script>
    
}
```

Is there anything I´m missing? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You need `onclick="clear()"`

Comment: The proper way is to call `reset()` on the form; you should also assign event listeners in code, not via attributes: https://jsfiddle.net/62f5gvhx/